# How to keep ActiveRecord objects with the same id separate in-memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Rails 3.1**. Here are my models

```
class Cookbook
  has_many :recipes, :include => :ingredients
end

class Recipe
  belongs_to :cookbook
  has_many :ingredients
end

class Ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

And I have this data

```
Cookbook (id: 1)
  Recipe "Pizza" (id: 1)
    Ingredient "Tomato" (id: 1)
    Ingredient "Cheese" (id: 2)
  Recipe "Spaghetti" (id: 2)
    Ingredient "Tomato" (id: 1)
    Ingredient "Pasta" (id: 3)
```

Now let us load the data as ActiveRecord objects

```
# Eager load all recipes and ingredients
cookbook = Cookbook.includes(:recipes).find(1)

pizza = cookbook.recipes[0]
tomato_for_pizza = pizza.ingredients.first

spaghetti = cookbook.recipes[1]
tomato_for_spaghetti = spaghetti.ingredients.first
```

However, I would like to set a flag on one of the ActiveRecord objects but don't want it to affect the other ActiveRecord object with the same id.

```
tomato_for_pizza.in_stock = true
tomato_for_spaghetti.in_stock     # true, but should be false (default)
```

In other words, I want the `Ingredient` objects (even though they both have the same id and represent the same data in the database) to be loaded as separate objects in-memory. In the language of RSpec

```
tomato_for_pizza.object_id.should_not == tomato_for_spaghetti.object_id
```

My question: Is this possible? Or is there an alternative way I could do this?

Comment: in rspec, you can write: `tomato_for_pizza.should_not be tomato_for_spaghetti`

Answer (score 0):

You can clone an object using `clone` method. More at [ruby-doc.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-clone)

If you will clone the desired object the clone will contain the same information, but the object_id will be different

Comment: Yea but how would I clone them while it's being eager loaded through ActiveRecord?

Comment: for rails 3.1 you should use dup instead of clone - that being said it seems very odd that you would have an entity (Ingredient) of 'tomato' where in_stock was different depending on its relation to a Recipe? how is in_stock determined if not from the database?  `tomato_for_pizza = pizza.ingredients.first.dup tomato_for_spaghetti = spaghetti.ingredients.first.dup`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to create another model

```
class RecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  attr_accessible :in_stock
end
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm not looking to persist the `in_stock` attribute in the database